# Painless script to increase the count if the full path exists or else add the full path and add the count

Tags: elasticsearch

I am creating a script to increase the count value of the field if the field full path exist, or else I have to add the full path dynamically. For example, In the below example

1. If the record already has `inner->board1->count`, I should increment the value of it by the value of the `count`
2. If I don't have `inner` or `board1` or `count`, I should add them and add the value of the `count`. Please also note here the  `inner or` board1`or`count` are not fixed.

If the value is not an object, I can check using `ctx._source.myCounts == null`, but I am not sure how to check for the object fields and subfields and sub subfields.

Code

```
POST test/_update/3
{
  "script": {
        "source": "ctx._source.board_counts = params.myCounts",
    "lang": "painless",
    "params": {
      "myCounts": {
        "inner":{
          "board1":{"count":5},
          "board2":{"count":4},
          "board3":{"temp":1,"temp2":3}
        },
          "outer":{
          "board1":{"count":5},
          "board10":{"temp":1,"temp2":3}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to come up with this and working fine.

```
POST test/_update/3
{
  "script": {
        "source": "{"source": "if (ctx._source['myCounts'] == null) {ctx._source['myCounts'] = [:];} for (mainItem in params.myCounts) { for (accessItemKey in mainItem.keySet()) { if (ctx._source.myCounts[accessItemKey] == null) { ctx._source.myCounts[accessItemKey] = [:];}for (boardItemKey in mainItem[accessItemKey].keySet()) {if (ctx._source.myCounts[accessItemKey][boardItemKey] == null) {ctx._source.myCounts[accessItemKey][boardItemKey] = [:];} for (countItemKey in mainItem[accessItemKey][boardItemKey].keySet()) { if (ctx._source.myCounts[accessItemKey][boardItemKey][countItemKey] == null) { ctx._source.myCounts[accessItemKey][boardItemKey][countItemKey] =mainItem[accessItemKey][boardItemKey][countItemKey]; }else {ctx._source.myCounts[accessItemKey][boardItemKey][countItemKey] += mainItem[accessItemKey][boardItemKey][countItemKey];}}}}}",
    "lang": "painless",
    "params": {
      "myCounts": {
        "inner":{
          "board1":{"count":5},
          "board2":{"count":4},
          "board3":{"temp":1,"temp2":3}
        },
          "outer":{
          "board1":{"count":5},
          "board10":{"temp":1,"temp2":3}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```